# How to approximate the convex hull of a curved letter to a quadrilateral?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have an input image such as:
[image: input image]

Which will turn out after being preprocessed as:
[image: preprocessed image]

Now, this image is a little bit inclined and what I want to do is to fix it with `cv2.warpPerspective()`.

So, in order to do that, I generate a quadrilateral approximating (with `cv2.approxPolyDP()`) the convex hull. This is the actual code that I use:

```py
hull = cv2.convexHull(contour)

# Reduce to quadrilateral
epsilon = 0.1 * cv2.arcLength(hull, True) 
approximated = cv2.approxPolyDP(hull, epsilon, True)
```

The convex hull of that preprocessed image looks like this:
[image]

But, when I approximate it, I get the following results:
[image]

What I want to achieve is something like this:
[image]

Here's an example on how it works with a letter without curves:
[image]

Which will get transformed into:

[image]

In short, the issue lays when approximating the convex hull to a quadrilateral.
How can I achieve such quadrilateral on a letter with curves?

Here's the full code that I have written to do that:

```py
def _perspective_fix_convex_hull(self):
    # RETR_TREE retrieves all of the contours and reconstructs a full hierarchy of nested contours
    # used for maximum accuracy (my deduction)
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(self.preprocessed_image, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    # Draw all contours to a new image
    self.image_contours = cv2.cvtColor(self.preprocessed_image, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
    cv2.drawContours(self.image_contours, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)

    self.convex_hulls_contours = []
    self.approximated_contours = []
    for contour in contours:
        # Get contour area
        
        area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
        if area < 200:
            # Too small for a letter
            continue

        image = cv2.cvtColor(self.preprocessed_image, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

        hull = cv2.convexHull(contour)
        cv2.drawContours(image, [hull], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)

        self.convex_hulls_contours.append(image)

        # Reduce to quadrilateral
        epsilon = 0.1 * cv2.arcLength(hull, True) 
        approximated = cv2.approxPolyDP(hull, epsilon, True)

        # Draw approximated contour
        image = cv2.cvtColor(self.preprocessed_image, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
        cv2.drawContours(image, [approximated], -1, (255, 0, 0), 1)

        self.approximated_contours.append(image)

        if len(approximated) == 4:
            image = cv2.cvtColor(self.preprocessed_image, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
            cv2.drawContours(image, [approximated], -1, (0, 0, 255), 2)

            self.final_contour = image

            letter_hull = [a[0] for a in approximated] # Remove extra dimension [[x, y]] -> [x, y]
            break

    # Create placeholder for rectangle points
    rectangle = np.zeros((4, 2), dtype="float32")

    # Top-left point has smallest sum
    # Bottom-right point has largest sum
    # sum = x + y
    s = np.sum(letter_hull, axis=1)
    rectangle[0] = letter_hull[np.argmin(s)]
    rectangle[2] = letter_hull[np.argmax(s)]

    # Top-right point has smallest difference
    # Bottom-left point has largest difference
    # difference = x - y
    d = np.diff(letter_hull, axis=1)
    rectangle[1] = letter_hull[np.argmin(d)]
    rectangle[3] = letter_hull[np.argmax(d)]

    # Compute width and height of new image based on points
    (top_left, top_right, bottom_right, bottom_left) = rectangle

    # Width may be either top-right to top-left or bottom-right to bottom-left
    # TL;DR: Pythagorean theorem 
    width_top = np.sqrt(((top_right[0] - top_left[0]) ** 2) + ((top_right[1] - top_left[1]) ** 2))
    width_bottom = np.sqrt(((bottom_right[0] - bottom_left[0]) ** 2) + ((bottom_right[1] - bottom_left[1]) ** 2))
    width = max(int(width_top), int(width_bottom))

    # Height may be either top-right to bottom-right or top-left to bottom-left
    # TL;DR: Pythagorean theorem 
    height_right = np.sqrt(((top_right[0] - bottom_right[0]) ** 2) + ((top_right[1] - bottom_right[1]) ** 2))
    height_left = np.sqrt(((top_left[0] - bottom_left[0]) ** 2) + ((top_left[1] - bottom_left[1]) ** 2))
    height = max(int(height_right), int(height_left))

    # Create destination points
    destination = np.array([
        [0, 0],
        [width - 1, 0],
        [width - 1, height - 1],
        [0, height - 1]
    ], dtype="float32")

    # Compute perspective transform matrix
    matrix = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(rectangle, destination)
    warped = cv2.warpPerspective(self.preprocessed_image, matrix, (width, height))

    # Add padding
    self.warped_image = cv2.copyMakeBorder(warped, 10, 10, 10, 10, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value=(0, 0, 0))
```

Comment: I can't understand why you don't use the background rectangle. From only the letter's contour is impossible in general, I think. You will need some hints, for example the pair of info {`letter is S` and the used font information}

Comment: @fana I can't use the rectangle because it won't be there in real cases. Imagine you are taking a picture of the S on a white background, there won't be any rectangle behind it since it will get thresholded as "all black". As for the font, we can assume that it will be the same of the one in the picture.

Comment: The convex hull is not going to work on S shape or on A shape.  You should just get the contour of the white background and use that. With the S letter, you could get the contour an then use cv2.minAreaRect() to find the enclosing rectangle. But that will not be a true perspective quadrilateral.

Comment: @fmw42I understand, thank you.